# What is a good way to structure a library which should work in OSGI- and non-OSGI environments?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox

I am writing an application which runs in an OSGI environment.
Now I want to extract some code and put it in separate bundle/jar file to reuse it also in other applications (both, OSGI or non-OSGI).

My goal is to remove any dependencies to the OSGI environment classes, because it should also run in other apps which do not have all the jars of the various OSGI frameworks (e.g. Equinox). But at the same time I would like to register an OSGI Service in the OSGI environment if the Application is an OSGI app.

I have already separated the code and the only remaining piece of OSGI-dependent code is currently my Activator class which registers some class as an OSGI Service:

```
context.registerService(MyServiceInterface.class.getName(), new MyServiceImpl(), new Hashtable());
```

To remove the dependency, I think about the following:

- I remove the Activator and OSGI dependencies from my bundle1
- I create another bundle2 where I move the Activator

In the end I have my bundle1.jar which only has a Manifest.mf file to make it OSGI-ready, but there is no code anymore depending on OSGI framework classes.
I have another bundle which only belongs to my current application which imports bundle1.jar and has the only purpose of registering the MyService.class on the OSGI container using an activator.

1. Is this approach ok or are there any other best practices?
2. Is registering a service in the OSGI environment good practice or is this something which always the host application should be responsible for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just leave the activator class in your bundle. When run in a non-OSGi environment, the activator class will not be called. When run in an OSGi environment, it will. Isolating you OSGi dependencies to the activator is a fine strategy.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that the Activator has import statements for the org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator and org.osgi.framework.BundleContext which will lead to compile errors in non-OSGI environments. That's what I try to avoid

Comment: Are you saying you don't even want to have OSGi libraries on your build path?? Why not, what's the cost? I understand removing OSGi from your runtime dependencies...

Comment: well, i haven't thought about this yet. So is it valid practice to do this? I would be fine with this, as our build path does have these dependencies (using pde build currently). I am planning to release this as a library on github providing a maven pom.xml, that's why I thought about making it as lightweight as possible for non-osgi applications. but that is my first open source release and I am thinking the first time about this kind of things.

Comment: If all the use of OSGi api in your bundle is limited to the activator class and that class is not used by any one else, then consumer's of your jar should be able to compile against your jar without the need for the OSGi API jars on the classpath. Obviously, if someone wants to recompile the source for your jar, they will need the OSGi API jars on the classpath to compile your activator class.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you can publish your service without Activator. Take a look at [OSGI Comunity Wiki](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services) and [Equinox example](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/05/12/osgi-declarative-services/).

Comment: Yeah the Declarative Services approach is probably the best approach here. In my case I don't want to switch to DS yet, so I will remove the Activator from my Service bundle and have another bundle which contains the Activator. That way my Service Bundle is completely OSGI-independent except the Manifest.MF with some package imports and export definitions.

Comment: If you use maven, you can just set the scope for osgi framework dependencies to provided.

Comment: Sounds like very bad practice since it requires exporting the service implementation class (MyServiceImpl)?
My choice would be to use a DS XML file ...

Comment: @PeterKriens right, that's bad. hmm I think I need to investigate into  DS then.

Comment: Take a look at spring-dm and aries blueprint.

Comment: DS is *much* simpler and more reliable (no grace period, better recovery from failure) than either spring-dm or bp ...

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use blueprint. At least in simple cases it allows to have no dependencies to OSGi at all. For real world cases you typically need at least some OSGi APIs but it is no problem to leave them simply inactive in the non OSGi case.

You may also want to try [PojoSR](http://code.google.com/p/pojosr/). It allows to use Activators and OSGi Services outside OSGi. We started to use this in Apache Camel to test OSGi code.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring-DM would help remove code dependency to OSGi. Your bundle wouldn't need an activator and the service can be exported from the spring-dm config xml. However, this does add a lot more runtime dependencies, but no compile dependencies are needed.